# What is the "yes" command used for?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, shell

On my Linux 4.15 machine I found the `yes` command that appears completely useless - it outputs a string passed as argument (default: `'y'`) repeatedly untill killed. And... that's it.

```bsh
name@machine:~$ yes
y
y
[...]
y
y
^C
```

I have trouble figuring out a possible use case for this, especially given that a simple `while true; do echo y; done` has similar behavior and is more readable (but I can't find any case for it either).

What can this command be used for?  Where does it comes from? Neither the man page nor the [full doc](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/yes-invocation.html#yes-invocation) answer these questions!

Comment: If you're running a command or script that is going to prompt you for multiple confirmations, you can pipe yes into it and it automatically answer y without the need for any further interaction on your part.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The command is used to automate scripts of programs where you have a prompt waiting for user input in the form of "press 'y/n' to continue". But there are also other use cases.

See [What is the point of the “yes” command?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/47344/what-is-the-point-of-the-yes-command)